# Can I rely on SDL_Surface::pitch being constant?

Tags: sdl

I'm working on a project which utilises `SDL 1.2.15`. The application constructs a `SDL_Surface` whose frame buffer is then retreived via `getDisplaySurface()->pixels` and sent via serial line.

I learned, that the pixel buffer pointed to by `SDL_Surface::pixels` is not necessarily continuous. The byte sequence might be interrupted by blocks of data which are not part of the visible image area.

That means the image is of size 320×240, but the pixel buffer could be of size, let's say, 512×240. (I imagine speedups possible due to memory alignment could be a valid reason. That's just my assumption which is not backed by actual knowledge, though.)

---

**Question:**

In my case, I happen to be lucky and the the pixel buffer has exactly the dimensions of my image. Can I trust that the pixel buffer dimensions wouldn't change?

That way I could just send the pixel buffer content to the serial interface and don't have to write code dealing with removal of those invalid blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDL [uses](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/4de9d54bbc87/src/video/SDL_pixels.c#l744) 4-byte alignment for rows. It also matches OpenGL's [default alignment](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glPixelStorei.xml).

Comment: My bad, I mixed up width and height.